# SQL Server Express - TVP Parameterized TVF with recursive CTE freezing at execution

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, table-valued-parameters, recursive-cte, table-functions

Just came across a very strange server behavior - namely:

I got TVF with one TVP argument as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [BUD].[Foo] (@IdAgrs IdTable READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH recursive_CTE
    AS
    (
            --> Select here is not important - only that TVP join goes here:

            SELECT Id, IdParent, Number, 1 as 'lvl'
            FROM Agreements ag
                join @IdAgrs ig on ig.Id = ag.Id   --> HERE

            UNION ALL

            SELECT a.Id, a.IdParent, a.Number
                i.lvl + 1
            FROM Agreements e
                INNER JOIN recursive_CTE r ON e.IdParent = r.Id
    )
    select 1
    from recursive_CTE
)
```

Heres TVP:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from sys.table_types where name = 'IdTable')
    CREATE TYPE IdTable AS TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL)
```

Now the "strange" part:

When trying to execute a function on the express server version - it freezes. I mean that the execution time is sooo long (I cancel execute after 4min of waiting) while on full version it goes without a problem (0s - no data at all). Both are 2008R2, same DB, same TVF, same TVP. Execution of TVF as below

```
declare @IdAgrs IdTable
insert into @IdAgrs values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)

select * from BUD.Foo(@IdAgrs)
```

But!

When i execute the body of the TVF alone - it works like a charm (WTF?)

```
declare @IdAgrs IdTable
insert into @IdAgrs values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)

;WITH recursive_CTE
AS
(
    --> Select here is not important - only that TVP join goes here:

    SELECT Id, IdParent, Number, 1 as 'lvl'
    FROM Agreements ag
        join @IdAgrs ig on ig.Id = ag.Id   --> HERE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.Id, a.IdParent, a.Number
        i.lvl + 1
    FROM Agreements e
        INNER JOIN recursive_CTE r ON e.IdParent = r.Id
)
select 1
from recursive_CTE
```

I have no idea why?!
Whether express edition have some limitations or what?

Comment: When it's blocked what wait type do you see in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` for that session? Also are you setting a non default `MAXRECURSION` level in an `OPTION` clause?

Comment: And are the execution plans the same for both?

Comment: No `OPTION` clause at all. Anyway theres no data to iterate through. About wait type I really have no idea - what to look for? I checked before and during the execution - no change (only column `wait_duration_ms`).

Comment: I can't check it on express edition because when I'm tring to the  function execution is infinite (i have to cancel it). When I checked it on full server version - execution plans are the same.

Comment: To display an estimated execution plan (without running the query) press Ctrl-L in Management Studio (or click the appropriate icon). If *that* hangs, you've found a bug and should check your server version against the latest SP/CU.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah, I also checked this immediately after a proper execution plan did not go and unfortunately it hangs too.

Comment: And the results were...? Same execution plan, presumably, or you would have mentioned otherwise? Feel free to update your original question so we can delete these comments.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Comment updated. It hangs too. I'll compare versions but I'll be able to do this tomorrow.

Comment: I checked the server version and it's `10.50.1600` a.k.a. clear 2008 R2 installation. So it's possible that it is actually a server error. I can't say that now because it's not on my machine, nor do I have physical access to it. I gave information about an update so now I just have to wait for feedback. I'll post the answer if that helped as soon as I receive that feedback.

Comment: Too old but IMO using a `;` before `WITH` can be helpful ;).